# What is the push_back method used for in OpenGL?

Tags: c++

What is the purpose of the `push_back` method in OpenGL?  I was trying to understand a obj model loader program, specifically the following code:

```
while(!in.eof())
{
    in.getline(buf,256);    //dosyanýn sonunda deðilken, coord vektörü
                            // için herþeyi okur. Bir string olarak okur.
    coord.push_back(new std::string(buf));
}
```

I have some ideas about `push_back` but I want to be sure.

Comment: The current answer doesn't explicitly state this, but `push_back` as used in that piece of code is not related to OpenGL at all.

Comment: just googling "push_back" would have helped as much as asking here.

Comment: Google translate says the comment in the code means "[deðilken] at the end of the file, reads everything to vector coord. Reads as a string."

Comment: Hm, `new std::string`? Why would anyone want a `std::vector<std::string*>`?

Comment: I don't know what language that comment is in, but I hope it says something like "don't do this, fixed size buffers are bad"

Answer (score 2):

push_back is a standard vector function which adds an entry to the end of the vector:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/

Comment: Note that here the term `vector` has nothing to do with the 3d graphics term. `vector` is just part of the C++ standard library and has nothing to do with OpenGL. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Good point.  Vector is a data structure in the programming world, vector in the mathematical (opengl) sense, is essentially a coordinate [sometimes with a direction and/or velocity].  It's being used here with the push_back function as a data structure.